# Finding correct lat and lot

Tags: javascript, python, geolocation

Do you know any way to find correct location (lon,lat) using python or js 
I am trying the following python code but it doesnt give me my correct current location

```
import json
from urllib.request import urlopen
from requests import get
import geocoder
url = 'http://ipinfo.io/json'
response = urlopen(url)
data = json.load(response)

g = geocoder.ip('me')
print(g.latlng)
"""loc = get('https://ipapi.co/{}/json/'.format(data['ip']))
print(loc.json())"""

send_url = 'http://freegeoip.net/json'
r = get(send_url)
j = json.loads(r.text)
lat = j['latitude']
lon = j['longitude']
print("lat {} lon {}".format(lat, lon))
```

Comment: well, it will give you the lat/lon that the service in that webpage returns to you, so the problem is which service are you using not the current code right?

Comment: the problem is that i get an output but it is not correct 30 km mistake

Answer (score 1):

Your IP Address doesn't/can never give you the correct location of where you are it.  The location can from the internet can only be used to get the country and MAYBE the state of the user.

The location given is usually where the Sub-Station of your ISP is located.

Comment: no, there is now way of finding the exact lat and lon from an IP Address.  I mean it makes sense.  Imagine everyone can see where you are from etc.

Answer (score 0):

In javascript you can do this

```
let position;
navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition((pos) => position = pos.coords && 
console.log(position));
```

after that you can just do:

-position.latitude

-position.longitude

It's not the most accurate precision, but in chase you want something more precise, you can look for watchPosition() of Geolocation in MDN documentation.